# What was original Jailbreak detection API Apple just removed in 4.2?

Tags: api, ios4, detection, jailbreak, appstore-approval

Apple seems to be removed the jailbreak detection API, as announced in http://www.engadget.com/2010/12/12/apple-mysteriously-kills-jailbreak-detection-api-while-hacker-bo
What was the original API removed?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, it was a server based API that basically made the phone tell the server if it was jailbroken, then apply the necessary actions to make sure somebody knew the phone was jailbroken.  It was only used in enterprise situations, so for the most part, no normal people had to be worried.  As a matter of fact, musclenerd [tweeted](http://twitter.com/MuscleNerd/status/13794567513972737) that the iphone dev team didn't even attempt to fool it because they didn't think it was really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The reason most possibly is: jailbreaking  has become legal through a court decision. So there is no reason for Apple to track hacked devices, it would even be intrusive to your private sphere.